# How can I find the value of these resistors in this power supply?

Tags: power-supply, power, resistors

I am trying to repair this power supply but these two resistors are burned.   How can I find the value of these resistors?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make a sharper picture of the board where the resistors go.  At least some of the resistor values are marked on that board.

Comment: find someone who's taken a good photo of a working one,.

Comment: @Dave: Dang.  The ones you need don't have values marked.  Look over by that big capacitor, and you'll see a couple of places marked with resistor values.  I hoped they'd all be marked that way.

Comment: Look up the part number on that 8-pin IC and see if its datasheet has a reference design schematic which looks anything like your board. That may give you some hints for resistor values.

Comment: One of those appears to be a gate resistor for that MOSFET, so likely it's fried too, as well as its driver circuit

Comment: Forget it - Invest your efforts in sourcing a new supply.   Resistors rarely just fail for no reason - Something else failed and took those resistors with it.  Replace the resistors, they'll fry again.   To be blunt - If you are asking this question, then you do not have the experience to troubleshoot a switching power supply, especially w/o a schematic.  The shotgun approach of 'just replace components' rarely works.

Comment: @KyleB why should i forget it ? every professional technician were beginner and now I'm beginner. and i know why these resister are fail. my question is about how to find resistor ohm when we can't read the number on board and color on it. if you can help you are welcome, but you should not think that I think that way.

Comment: @Dave   Trying to save you time.  If you're doing this for the challenge, have at it.   But I wouldn't have high hopes you'll solve this one.    What you have on-hand is an "open frame switching power supply".  These are WAY more common than you think.  If you know the output voltages & currents, you should be able to find a suitable replacement for about $25.     https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/ac-dc-converters/923?s=N4IgTCBcDaIPYAcCmA7ABAMwE4EMC2SaCcA7klmgM4CuCCANgJ4gC6AvkA

Comment: The answer to your question is "you can't".  Without a schematic, or without some other known good board to reference, there is no way for you (or anybody else) to tell you the "right" values.   The suggestion above about searching relevant datasheets for clues is about the best you'll probably do.

Comment: @KyleB thank you. i do this just for challenge, i think with know the value of other component i cant find the value. but you say nobody can find it. but i still think if for example these resistor on the way of transistor gate and knowing it input voltage we can find it. but because I'm beginner in repair, i cant solve this alone.

Comment: If you really wanna have a serious go, and there's no schematic available, a good starting point is trying to reverse engineer the circuit.   Use your meter, take your time and draw the schematic out (at least the parts you're interested in).

Answer (score 1):

R6 is the gate stopper resistor, so 22R would be a good start. R12 is in the current sense circuit, so my guess is around 1K. As others have mentioned, there’s collateral damage. The 3842 controller chip is most likely fried. There may be a zener in the gate circuit that is fried and so on.

Power supplies using the ucc3842 tend to follow much the same pattern. The datasheet has a generic circuit that might give some hints.

When you replace the low ohm current sense resistors - don’t use wire-wound types due to inductance.